# Find number in txt file in C language

Tags: c

I have this function that im gonna use to find a number in txt file, how can i get the function to look for the number i give in all the lines and then show only the line of that specific number?

the lines in txt file are like this:

```
9119201 Analise Matematica              S1  6   75 h
9119202 Algebra Linear                  S1  5   60 h
9119203 Fisica Aplicada                 S1  6   75 h
```

and this is the function:

```
void acrescentaUc (int *quantUcs)
{
    int num;
    FILE *arq;
    char *ucnr;
    char Linha[100];
    if (*quantUcs == MAXUCS)
    {
        printf("\n\nATENCAO: Impossivel inserir nova Uc devido ao limite maximo atingido\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Insira numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if(num < MIN_NRUC || num > MAX_NRUC)
        {
            printf("ERRO: Numero de UC Invalido");
        }
        else
        {
            arq = fopen("ListaUcs.txt", "rt");

            if (arq == NULL)
            {
                printf("ERRO na abertura do ficheiro\n");
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0; i < 40; i++)
                {
                    ucnr = fgets(Linha, 100, arq);
                    if (ucnr)
                    {
                        // Se foi possível ler
                        printf("%s",Linha);
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose(arq);
        }
        limpaBufferStdin();
        printf("\n\nUc adicionada\n\n");
        (*quantUcs)++;


    }

}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you actually check for the number? If you want to process multiple lines then you need to call `fgets` and the check code in a loop.

Comment: Please provide a [Minmal Reproducable Ex.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I suggest you learn about `while` and `for` loops

Comment: Im checking the number in this lines                                                                     printf("Insira numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

Comment: That's not checking. That's just getting the input number from the user. Where do you then use the number for checking against a line in the file?

Comment: i edit the question, because i dont have that and i need help with that, sorry

Comment: You need to parse each line. One way to do that is to use `strtok` to break the line up into each part. And then use `strtol` to convert the last token on the line to an integer. Suggest you break up the problem into smaller parts. Start by writing a function that does that by taking a string (one line of input) and an int and returns true or false.

Comment: I really appreciate that explanation but this is from a school project, and in the school subject the teachers didnt give me that functions, do you have some other simple way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't give me that functions"? Those are standard C functions. If you can't use  them then you need to write them yourself which will be more complicated and not less.

Comment: i know these are standard functions but my teachers dont accept that , i know its stupid but its the true